# Is there any way to use a GUI app or website inside GCP from AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, vpn, aws-vpn

We have an website inside a private VPC in GCP, but we want to securely access it from an AWS Client VPN we are already using to access other websites running in AWS infrastructure.

Is this even doable? I have been reading AWS Client VPN endpoint documentation but it seems to only work with internet AWS services to expose them to on premises client networks but not to expose external services such as ours in GCP.

Comment: In general, yes. I connect from AWS <-> GCP all the time. Is your goal to use a VPN client application running in AWS to connect to a system running in GCP that does not have a public IP address? Your question lacks details on what is configured. Those details are required to answer your question. Typically when connecting cloud networks you use site-to-site VPNs and not client-to-site VPNs (remote access). Take a look at WireGuard (poor man VPN), which I use to network private systems together. Only one system requires a public IP address.

Comment: What about [an AWS site to site VPN[( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html) ?  Though AWS VPN is painfully expensive; if that matters to you (and to whom does it not!?!) Wireguard is worth considering.